# How can I pass id/class of a button present in a handlebar file into the typescript to launch a react modal when button is clicked

Tags: reactjs, handlebars.js

I have created a handlebar file which has a button in it, now I want to pass this button's  id/class into the typescript so that I can launch a react modal on click of this button from typescript.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( '#' + the same ID ).on( 'click', function() {
    $( '#id_modal' ).modal('show');
} )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="{{id}}">
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).